# Is a hard drive image of a virtual machines drive applicable on the host machines hard drive

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, images, iso-image, clonezilla

I have installed Ubuntu on the hard drive of my desktop computer. 
In Ubuntu I installed VirtualBox to test some Distributions in a virtual machine.

Lets say I like some Distribution while discovering it in my virtual machine, I installed some applications and now I want to use that setup on my host computer.

I can make an image of the hard drive of the virtual machine where the Distribution is installed. Is it possible that I apply this image (again with clonezilla) on the hard drive of the host computer which runs the virtual machine?

Comment: Are all your guest OSs Ubuntu only?

Comment: No also, also Gentoo, Arch, Fedora.